# Scala Future concurrency Issue

Tags: multithreading, scala

Following is my class where I run tasks concurrently. My problem is , my application never ends even after getting result for all the features. I suspect Thread pool is not shutting down which leads my application alive even after my tasks.Believe me I googled alot to figure it out but no luck. What I'm missing here?

```
 import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    import scala.util.Failure
    import scala.util.Success

    object AppLauncher{

      def launchAll(): ListBuffer[Future[String]] = {
        // My code logic where I launch all my threads say 50
        null
      }

def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {
register(launchAll())
}



      def register(futureList: ListBuffer[Future[String]]): Unit =
        {
          futureList.foreach { future =>
            {
              future.onComplete {
                case Success(successResult) => {
                  println(successResult)
                }
                case Failure(failureResult) => { println(failureResult) }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you create these futures? I tried to run the example. I created dummy Futures with ListBuffer.fill(50)(Future("asd")). The main body finished before anything was printed to the console. I added Thread.sleep(1000) after register method call. The program printed asd twenty times and closed after 1000 seconds. So maybe there is a problem with your futures or something? Could you provide more details about your threads?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out the issue.The issue is certianly  because  of Thread Pool was not terminated even after my futures were completed successfully . I tried to isolate the issue by changing my implementation slightly as below.

> //import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

```
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
  import scala.util.Failure
  import scala.util.Success

  //Added ExecutionContex explicitly 
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import concurrent.ExecutionContext

  object AppLauncher {

    //Implemented EC explicitly 
    private val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000)
    private implicit val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

    def launchAll(): ListBuffer[Future[String]] = {
      // My code logic where I launch all my threads say 50
      null
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      register(launchAll())
    }

    def register(futureList: ListBuffer[Future[String]]): Unit =
      {
        futureList.foreach { future =>
          {

            println("Waiting...")
            val result = Await.result(future, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration.Inf)

            println(result)

          }

        }
```

> ```
>         pool.shutdownNow()
>         executionContext.shutdownNow()
> ```

```
        println(pool.isTerminated() + " Pool terminated")
        println(pool.isShutdown() + " Pool shutdown")

        println(executionContext.isTerminated() + " executionContext terminated")
        println(executionContext.isShutdown() + " executionContext shutdown")
      }

  }
```

**Result before adding highlighted code to shutdown pools**

> false  Pool terminated
>
> true Pool shutdown
>
> false executionContext terminated
>
> true executionContext shutdown

After adding highlighted code solved my issue. I ensured no resource leak in my code.My scenario permits me to kill the pool when all the futures are done. I'm aware of the fact that I changed elegant callback implementation to blocking implementation but still it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you operate on an iterable of `Future`s you should use `Future.sequence` which changes say, a `Seq[Future[T]]` to a `Future[Seq[T]]`.

So, use something like:

```
def register(futureList: Seq[Future[String]]) = Future.sequence(futureList) foreach { results =>
  println("received result")
}
```

if you'd like to map each future and print outputs as it completes, you can also do something on the lines of;

```
def register(futureList: Seq[Future[String]]) = Future.sequence (
  futureList.map(f => f.map { v =>
    println(s"$v is complete")
    v
  }) ) map { vs =>
  println("all values done $vs")
  vs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried with  Future.sequence(futureList)  but the result is same

Comment: can you tell me how your launchAll() method starts all the Futures?

Comment: Future[String] {
//My buss logics goes here
} Lets say i will be having more than one Futures will be called dynamically based on the circumstances

Comment: That is what I'm interested in. Could it be that you're Future never completes?

Comment: I tried checking status of the Futures using future.isCompleted() method. it returns true

Comment: @BalajiReddy You must be blocking the main thread .. unknowingly. You should paste the method code as well